# How to use request inside of ViewClass

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Im working recycle django polls app tutorial
I've created Question model which contains authorized field, where i store id of users who are authorized to see questions

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    users = User.objects.values_list('id','username')
    authorized = MultiSelectField(choices=users,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{question_text}".format(question_text=self.question_text)
```

I'm having a problem with writing my view, because idk how to use  `flask import request`  to get user id to show only those questions which are designed for logged in user

```
class VotesView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/votes.html'
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(request):
        return Question.objects.filter(authorized__icontains=request.user.id)
```

Keep getting error:

```
    return Question.objects.filter(authorized__icontains=request.user)
AttributeError: 'VotesView' object has no attribute 'user'
```

or

```
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Thanks for any help, i stucked for 2 days

Comment: Well `get_queryset` has only one parameter: `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in Django the first parameter of an *instance* method is the `self`, a reference to the object that is currently called. So you should rewrite it with a `self` parameter.

Now of course our `self` is *not* a request. But the good news is: a `ListView` has a `.request` attribute and so we can obtain the user through that `.request` attribute:

```
class VotesView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/votes.html'
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(
            authorized__icontains=self.request.user.id
        )
```